# System freezing... No way of capturing the reason why?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, fglrx, crash

I have a PC that has a number of peripherals connected to it that is intermittently experiencing a freeze of the OS.  There are 6+ USB devices and four monitors connected to the PC.

Details of system:
- CPU: AMD RX-427BB
- Graphics: PCI Express card AMD E8860 (fglrx driver)
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.4
- Kernel: 4.2.0-41-generic

When the system freezes, I cannot use the mouse, keyboard, and networking seems to be down (no ping/ssh).

I tried to turn on kernel crash dumps (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html), but I'm not capturing any dumps.  The system will just hang indefinitely rather than restarting after grabbing a dump.

Are there scenarios where there could be a crash and I wouldn't see a dump?  Is there anything else that can be done if I can't get a kernel dump?  There isn't considerable of value if syslog or kern.log before the crash, but I do so see these few messages of interest:

kernel: [    8.442287] <3>[fglrx:cf_object_handle_cmd] *ERROR* Can not generate cf candidates

Comment: How much memory you have ? Run `free -h` command in terminal and add output to your post

Comment: The kernel message you provide seems to relate to graphics though

Comment: Look in `/var/log/kern.log*` for the first messages the system logs when it comes up (the time field is "`[    0.000000]`", and read the lines before that one.  They may contain hints.

Comment: I'm running at 55% memory utilization and 25% CPU usage on average.

I agree that the error message is graphics related, but I've seen all kinds of fglrx issues (although it seemed to be more related to the initial 4.2 kernel release).

kern.log and syslog are suspiciously quiet during their last messages before the crash (ie above 0.000000).  That is why I turned on kernel crash dumps hoping to get more out of it.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the kernel crash dumps are actually catching a panic.